# Make Individual Folders From .txt Files In A Folder With Powershell

Tags: powershell, file, directory, zip

Beginner here! So preemptive apologies. Most of what I've used has just been slightly modified code, and I've just started learning the real basics so I can stop modifying and making it myself.

I've got a folder full of .txt files and I need to make a script (still just dipping my toe, so I don't have a start) that makes a folder for each text file. From that point I need to also have a PDF or two copied into each of the folders. Then each of them zipped.

So what I'm hoping to accomplish with this would be if my List folder of text files is full of:

123.txt
234.txt
345.txt (and so on)

That I end up with a folder full of folders containing the text file, each folder with the same name as the text file, so:

ListFolder > (folder)123 (folder)234 (folder)345, where (folder)123 contains 123.txt, (folder)234 contains 234.txt, and so on.

Then I have a PDF or two, that I want to copy into each of those folders, so (folder)123 would contain 123.txt, PDF1, and PDF2. And have that happen to each folder so they all contain the original txt file as well as the PDF or two.

Then just have them individually zip, taking each folder with 3 files (if there were 2 PDF files) and ending with 123.zip, 234.zip, 345.zip, and so on.

I hope that made sense. There's just numerous steps involved that I know have to have a way to be simplified. Some of these folders will have hundreds of txt files, so you can imagine how tedious that would be by hand. Thanks for any help and guidance!

Comment: Please [format your code and sample input/output properly](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22189/248777).

Comment: How do you know, which PDF goes into which folder?

Comment: I will have one or two PDFs, they're just to be copied into every folder so every folder has both the proper txt file, as well as a copy of the PDF(s). Right now I just email people a PDF or two and they have to copy a blank version of them for each txt file, which is what I'm trying to automate so they don't have to copy the file over and over themselves

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just wrote a small script which does what you need with the txt files. For the pdf files you need to specify which pdf goes into which folder!

## Full Script

```
$path = "C:\temp\txt\" #Path where all the TXT files are
$pdfpath = "C:\temp\pdf\" #Path where all the PDF Files are

$files = Get-Childitem $path | Where-Object { ! $_.PSIsContainer} #Get all files in the folder

#For each file in this folder
foreach ($file in $files){
    ## If it is a txt file
    if ([io.path]::GetExtension($file.Name) -eq ".txt"){ # If it is a .txt file
        $foldername = [io.path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($file) #Remove the fileextension in the foldername
        if (!(Test-Path "$path\$foldername")){ #If the folder doesn't exist
            New-Item "$path\$foldername" -ItemType "directory" #Create a new folder for the file
        }
        Move-Item $file.FullName "$path\$foldername" #Move file into the created folder
    }
}

#Create ZIP-Archive
$folders = Get-Childitem $path | Where-Object {$_.PSIsContainer} #Get all folders

foreach ($folder in $folders){
    Copy-Item -Path "$pdfpath\*" -Destination "$path\$folder" #Copy PDF into the folder
    Get-Childitem -Path "$path\$folder" | Compress-Archive -DestinationPath "$path\$folder.zip" #Zip the folder
    Remove-item "$path\$folder" -Force -Recurse #Remove the folder
}
```

Let me know if it worked. - Nicicalu

Comment: This is great! Thank you! I needed to add a closing brace, but it did exactly what I needed for the text files.. 

The PDFs will be the same for each folder, so it will be one, sometimes two, that are copied into every folder that is made from the txt files, and once all the files are in each folder, I need them to zip up individually. So theoretically, a folder of 100 txt files turns into a folder of 100 zip folders that include the txt file and the copied pdf(s)

Comment: @Trinity I finished the Script. This should work! Make sure you understand all the code, so next time you are able to do it your self or you can make minor changes. Please mark my post as the answer if it works :)

Comment: You're fantastic! I meant to also thank you for the documentation last time. I have found scripts that do bits of what I was looking for, I just wasn't sure how to go about putting them together, and modifying them for my needs. Most coding I see doesn't usually have the comments that are extremely helpful for beginners like me. Thank you so much, this works perfect!

Comment: @Trinity No problem ;) Glad it worked. Have a nice time with it